# select * from applies_jobs where appid like '%RAD-0001%' and job_id IN ('41,48,49') order by id asc

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

getting query empty with this query. butt data is there in database

```
 select * from applies_jobs where appid like '%RAD-0001%' and  job_id IN ('41,48,49') order by id asc
```

if i use only in or like query it work fine.

Comment: `IN(41,48,49)` w/o quotes.

Comment: IN (41,48,49) or IN ('41','48','49')

Comment: You might want to update the title of your question, and refactor your question it's self to describe the problem you're having. User's having a similar problem will find it easier to find your question (and answers) in the future...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
select * from applies_jobs where appid like '%RAD-0001%' and  job_id IN ('41','48','49') order by id asc
```

in the IN use separated values

Answer (score 0):

try this, removed single qoutes for integer value

```
    select * from applies_jobs where appid like '%RAD-0001%' and  job_id IN (41,48,49) order by id asc
```